# Nested insert_html bug : Ruby On Rails & Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Hey everyone! This problem is driving me absolutely insane! It seems like a bug in the rendering of JS by Rails but I'm not sure.

Brief synopsis:

I'm attempting to create a RELEASE which has_many TRACKs. These TRACKS have many TRACK_LINKS. These TRACK_LINKs then have associated TRACK_LINK_TYPEs (mp3, m3u, podcast, whatever). Think of it like an Album. So when adding a release, you can add the album tracks, and each album track can have different links (mp3, m3u, podcast, whatever). I'm at a very early stage and leveraging scaffolding - the user can create a release on the form, add tracks via JS and add track links via JS. This all works fine - but adding tracks does not work when I have the "Add Track Link" function in the code! It silently fails - no error, just goes to the # anchor.

In the main Release form i am rendering the TRACK partial and adding the link to add TRACKs:

```
<div id="tracks">
    <%= render :partial => 'track', :collection => @release.tracks -%>
</div>

<%= add_track -%>
```

Now in the TRACK partial, I am rendering the TRACK_LINK partial and adding the link to add TRACK_LINKs:

```
<div class="track">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Track</legend>
    <p> 
        <% @track = track %>
    <%= error_messages_for :track -%>

        <% fields_for_track(track) do |track_form| -%>
        Track Name
    <br />
    <%= track_form.text_field :name -%>
    <%= link_to_function "remove", "$(this).up('.track').remove()" -%>
    <% track_links_id = "track_links_#{Time.now.to_i.to_s}" %>
    <div id="<%= track_links_id %>">
            <%= render :partial => 'track_link', :collection => @track.track_links -%>              
    </div>
    <%= add_track_link track_links_id -%>   
    <% end -%>
    </p>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

And in the TRACK_LINK partial, I am creating the TRACK_LINK fields (with their associated TRACK_LINK_TYPE field):

```
<div class="track_link">
    <% @track_link = track_link -%>
<% fields_for_track_link(track_link) do |track_link_form| -%>
    Track Link
    <br />
    <%= track_link_form.text_field :url -%>
    <%= select ("track_link_type", "id", @track_link_type.map {|type| [type.name, type.id]}) -%>        
        <%= link_to_function "remove", "$(this).up('.track_link').remove()" -%>     
<% end -%>
</div>
```

Finally, here are the link_to_function helper methods:

```
module ReleasesHelper
    def fields_for_track(track, &block)
        prefix = track.new_record? ? 'new' : 'existing'
        fields_for("release[#{prefix}_track_attributes][]", track, &block)
    end

    def fields_for_track_link(track_link, &block)
        prefix = track_link.new_record? ? 'new' : 'existing'
        fields_for("track[#{prefix}_track_link_attributes][]", track_link, &block)
    end

    def add_track
        track = Track.new
        track.track_links.build
        link_to_function 'Add Track' do |page| 
            page.insert_html :bottom, :tracks, :partial => 'track', :object => track
    end
end

    def add_track_link(name)
        link_to_function "Add Track Link" do |page|       
            page.insert_html :bottom, name, :partial => 'track_link', :object => TrackLink.new
    end
end
end
```

The outcome is that each link_to_function works fine, but when I have the "Add Track" and "Add Track Link" functions at the same time, the "Add Track" link_to_function doesn't work. Something about it rendering the "Add Track Link" function is messing it up! Apologies for the long ass post! Hopefully its not annoying and someone can lend a hand?

best,
Praveen

Comment: I think I've seen something similar although I'm not sure what is causing it. I think what I did to get around it was use the equivalent Prototype code for the link_to_function that broke my other link. Does that fix things on your end?

Also, when I had similar problems it was the link_to_function that removed a previously rendered partial that was causing things to break, so it might be worth it to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon. The docs are good and it saves you writing and maintaining this code. If you're interested to know how it works, take a look at the source (it's not overly complex). Good luck!